# Grunt: insert filenames into files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Using Grunt.js, I need to read filenames of a series of JavaScript files in a directory, and insert part of each name into each of the files. I'm not finding a Grunt task that lets me do this.

So if my filename is `someFileName.js`, I would want the beginning of the file to look like:

```
var someFileName = ...
```

What is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[grunt-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-string-replace) appears to have what I need in recent release 1.3.0:

> Inject src and dest into the callback function when replacement is a
>   function; this allows the replacement function to use the old and/or
>   new file paths/names for further processing